# Private key not accessible / PEM / AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, private-key, pem

I'm trying to run a program on AWS/EC2 and am stuck into the launching of the instance.

1. .pem key file is created and linked to the instance. The key is saved in my documents.
2. Command "chmod 400 /Users/name_of_user/Documents/AI/AWS/cle/name_of_key.pem" reports no error
3. Command "ssh -i "name_of_key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-XX-YY-ZZZ-76.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" reports:

   ```
   Warning: Identity file name_of_key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
   ```
4. It then says:

> The authenticity of host
>   'ec2-XX-YY-ZZZ-76.us-west2.compute.amazonaws.com (XX.YY.ZZZ.76)' can't
>   be established.ECDSA key fingerprint is
>   SHA256:o6Vv2Doje9CyLv+YxbrlJaDcEGydZTYOmP0l3FBa5ps. Are you sure you
>   want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

5. I say 'yes' anyway. And then again the warning

> Warning: Identity file name_of_key.pem not accessible: No such file or
>   directory. Permission denied (publickey).

Do you know why the private key is not accessible? Should I save it in a special place?

Thank you very much

Comment: Supply the full path of the key to the `ssh` command. `ssh -i /Users/name_of_user/Documents/AI/AWS/cle/name_of_key.pem`

Comment: Yeah, are you in the right folder?

Comment: Yeeaaah! 'working!!! Thank you @MarkB

Comment: I was not!! Now it's ok!! Thank you @Henry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like ssh cannot find your key. You should use the key's absolute path:

```
ssh -i "/Users/name_of_user/Documents/AI/AWS/cle/name_of_key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-XX-YY-ZZZ-76.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

or `cd` into `/Users/name_of_user/Documents/AI/AWS/cle` and run

```
ssh -i "name_of_key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-XX-YY-ZZZ-76.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```